# simplexml is outputting bool(false) NULL

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

I have this very simple php code using simpleXML to display the xml in my page:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?&address=10005");
print_r($xml);
var_dump($xml, $http_response_header);
?>
```

I get a blank page with nothing it that's why i added the "var_dump" at the end and I get this on the web browser

```
bool(false) NULL
```

If you just copy and paste the url on your browser it will out the xml. So there is nothing wrong with the XML page. Also I do have my personal API key from google.
So i have no idea what "bool(false) NULL" is all about.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try: `simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?&address=10005'));`

Comment: nope, i get the same bool error

Comment: Keys are now required in request to the Google APIs

Comment: I have added my key on the parameters and i'm still getting the bool error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have to use either `cURL` or `file_get_contents()` to load data from external sources and try this

```
<?php

    //SOLUTION 1

    $url="http://-----";  //maps.googleapis.com with key
    $timeout = 60;
    $crl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    $xmlData = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    var_dump($xmlData);


     //SOLUTION 2

    $data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com with key");
    $xmlData = simplexml_load_file($data);
    var_dump($xmlData);
?>
```

Comment: The cURL solution works but how come the solution 2 with simplexml doesn't work? Solution 2 keeps saying bool(false)

Comment: because referring server must be enabled **allow_url_fopen** in their server if you are using **file_get_contents()**

Comment: so that would me that Google would have to allow my website to use the file_get_contents()?

Comment: since cURL is most secure and it just make http request like opening a website, but **file_get_contents()** is not secure as cURL and it is great for simple GET requests

Comment: Ok i have used a mix of both the first and second solution and that worked
$url="http://-----";
 $timeout = 60;
    $crl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($crl));
    curl_close($crl);